# how to install operating system on a virtual machine programatically

Tags: operating-system, installation, vmware

It may be a duplicate question but i could not find it anywhere.
Anyway, my goal to install operating system(both linux and windows) programatically on a virtual machine running on vmware hosts. 
Although my search, I am quite lost about where to start.
Is there a framework or project you can suggest?

Comment: What vmware hosts? if it is hosted (workstation/fusion), it comes with `EazyInstall` feature, where you can just mount your ISO, and provide minimal details like username/password etc, and rest is taken care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use templates; i.e. create a VM, install the Linux distribution of your choice and make the VM a template. Then don't create VMs but deploy the template.

Alternatively, google for the Linux distribution of your choice and something like "network installation". You'll need a DHCP server and probably a TFTP and/or web server.

[Working with Templates and Clones](http://www.vmwarehub.com/Working-with-templates-clones.html)

[Creating VMware Virtual Machine Templates](http://www.sysadmintutorials.com/tutorials/vmware-vsphere-4/vcenter4/creating-vmware-virtual-machine-templates/)

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at Vagrant: http://www.vagrantup.com/. It allows you to install/uninstall a predefined VM from the command line.

Comment: thank you for your response, but i am looking for more flexible framework. as long as i can see, i can only play around with vagrant. I have already finished creating VM on vCenter, now i want to continue to provision VM by installing the OS programatically.